# Mapping JSONArray in RestTemplate Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to map this JSONArray using Spring RestTemplate:

```
[{
    "Command": "/usr/sbin/sshd -D",
    "Created": 1454501297,
    "Id": "e00ca61f134090da461a3f39d47fc0cbeda77fbbc0610439d3c16a932686b612",
    "Image": "ubuntu:latest",
    "Labels": {

    },
    "Names": [
        "/nova-c1896fbd-1309-4da2-8d77-b4fe4c02fa8e"
    ],
    "Ports": [

    ],
    "Status": "Up 2 hours"
}, {
    "Command": "/usr/sbin/sshd -D",
    "Created": 1450106126,
    "Id": "7ffc9dbdd200e2c23adec442abd656ed57306955332697cb7da979f36ebf3b22",
    "Image": "ubuntu:latest",
    "Labels": {

    },
    "Names": [
        "/nova-93b9ae40-8135-48b7-ac17-12094603b28c"
    ],
    "Ports": [

    ],
    "Status": "Up 2 hours"
}]
```

Here is `ContainersInfo` class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ContainersInfo {


    private String Id;


    private List<String> Names;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return Names;
    }

    public void setNames(List<String> names) {
        Names = names;
    }
}
```

However I get `null` when I want to get the data:

```
ContainersInfo[] containers = syncRestTemplate.getForObject("http://192.168.1.2:4243/containers/json?all=1", ContainersInfo[].class);

for (int i = 0; i < containers.length; i++)
            System.out.println("id:" + containers[i].getId());
```

The resulting output is as follows:

> id:null
>
> id:null

Any idea, what I should do?

Comment: Are you sure your Labels part is object? Or it should be array?

Comment: I even don't try to map `Labels` I just try to get `Id` and `Names` in `ContainersInfo` class

Comment: Try removing     Labels .

Comment: @PradipBorde I can't do that, that's the JSON I receive from a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON field names are in pascal case as opposed to camel case (which is usually the case). Set Jackson naming strategy to `PascalCaseStrategy`, i.e by adding `@JsonNaming(PascalCaseStrategy.class)` annotation into `ContainersInfo` class.

Comment: yeah I know chrome extension to show JSON data in formatted way, changes that. That's not the issue.